# converting string to a double in visual c++ by parsing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone

In c# it is easy to use try parse method,but how to use this in visual c++.
I tried to use ToDouble, Parse...,but they are not recognized by visual studio by default.
if there is some namespace i should add to apply this please tell..

Comment: In standard C++ you have `strtod` (`#include <stdlib.h>`) and `std::stod` (`#include <string>`)

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: It isn't clear what environment you are actually targeting.  Visual Studio has a lot of different versions and a lot of languages, and there are a lot of versions of MS operating systems for phones.  What are you doing?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2013 guys. Language is of course visual c++ as i have previously mentioned.MS operating system of phone  is windows 8...keeping it short i tried "strtod" to convert string to double ex.
billamt = ::strtod(originalamt.c_str(), 0);
originalamt is my variable of string type.Now the error is c_str() is not defined in platform::string. Finally my question is simple , is there a simple way to convert string to double.

Comment: "Visual C++" is not a language.  It's the C++ support portion of Visual Studio and supports 3 languages: C++, C++/CLI, and C++/CX.  Which one of these are you using?

Comment: From your mention of platform::string (actually `Platform::String^` right?  Capitalization matters) you probably are using C++/CX.

Comment: By saying "string" instead of `std::string` or `System::String^` or `Platform::String^` you are really confusing the issue.

Comment: I am using c++/cx, I am using following namespaces:- using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace std;

Comment: c_str() is highlighted in red line in visual studio 2013, and when i  place my mouse pointer, it gives me this class "platform::string" has no member function c_str().Sorry for the confusion created here..i have many things to explore

Comment: That's true, except that you persist in misspelling `Platform::String` in lowercase.  `c_str()` is a member of `std::string` (which actually IS lowercase).  Looking for a way to do this with `Platform::String`

Comment: Instead of `originalamt.c_str()`, try `originalamt->Begin()` or `originalamt->Data()`.  Since it's Unicode, you'll then need `wcstod` instead of `strtod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows phone project is being developed using C++/CX which is the C++ interface to WinRT.

C++/CX represents string data using `Platform::String^`, a handle to a WinRT HSTRING.  These strings store arrays of Unicode characters, and you can get a `wchar_t*` via `s->Data()`.

Then you just need a C++ function that parses numeric data from a `wchar_t*`.  `wcstod`, which is the wide character version of `strtod`, is a great choice.

So your final code will end up looking something like:

```
wchar_t* end_parse;
double value = wcstod(s->Data(), &end_parse);
```

You can check whether the parse ended without processing the whole string, by looking at `*end_parse`.  Typically a successful parse will result in `*end_parse == L'\0'`, but if you are processing comma-separated values you might require that `*end_parse == L','`, and so on.